# Python Convert flat list of dicts to hierarchy tree

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tree, hierarchy

I've been having trouble trying to convert the following list:

```
lst = [
    {"id": 0, "job": "CEO", "ManagerID": 0, "name": "John Smith"},
    {"id": 1, "job": "Medical Manager", "ManagerID": 0, "name": "Medic 1"},
    {"id": 2, "job": "Medical Assist", "ManagerID": 1, "name": "Medic 2"},
    {"id": 3, "job": "ICT Manager", "ManagerID": 0, "name": "ICT 1"},
    {"id": 4, "job": "ICT Assist", "ManagerID": 3, "name": "ICT 2"},
    {"id": 5, "job": "ICT Junior", "ManagerID": 4, "name": "ICT 3"}
]
```

Into the format like

```
output = [
    {"id": 0, "job": "CEO", "ManagerID": 0, "name": "John Smith", "children" : [
        { "id":1, "job": "Medical Manager", "name": "Medic 1", "children" : [
            {"id": 2, "job": "Medical Assist", "name": "Medic 2"}
            ]
        },
        {"id": 3, "job": "ICT Manager", "name": "ICT 1", "children":[
            {"id": 4, "job": "ICT Assist", "name": "ICT 2", "children" : [
                {"id": 5, "job": "ICT Junior", "name": "ICT 3"}
            ]}
        ]}
    ],
}]
```

Were there is one root node (ManagerID = 0) any everything else branches off.

I've tried to adapt code from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35455882/6163866) but I was unable produce this required format

The code i've been using is as follows, but this still has repeats of parent nodes

```
classes = [] #everyones id
for item in lst:
    name = item['id']
    if name not in classes:
        classes.append(name)

treenodes = {}
root_node = None

for item in lst: # Create  tree nodes
    item['children'] = []
    name = item['id']
    treenodes[name] = item
    parent = item['ManagerID']
    if parent not in classes: # parent is root node, create
        if parent not in treenodes:
            node = {}
            node['ManagerID'] = 0 #set manager to root
            node['children'] = []
            node['id'] = parent
            root_node = node
            treenodes[parent] = node

# Connect parents and children
for item in lst: # Create  tree nodes
    parent = item['ManagerID']
    parent_node = treenodes[parent]
    parent_node['children'].append(item)

output = treenodes
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there any specific reason that the CEO gets to keep their `ManagerID` key in the output, but the rest of the hierarchy does not?

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444296/how-to-efficiently-build-a-tree-from-a-flat-structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is actually working, but you need to take the `treenodes[0]` entry (the CEO). The remainder of the key-value pairs in `treenodes` are there just for bookkeeping, to easily find the given manager for a given employee entry.

If you can't count on `0` being the ID of the root node, then you could use the fact that the CEO is marked as managing themselves; the root node is the one where the manager ID points to their own ID. A more common scenario is that root nodes simply do not have a parent ID.

You also added the CEO to their own `children` list (the manager ID for the CEO is their own ID), so you have a recursive reference in your tree.

The code you found is not the clearest or most efficient. I'd build a dictionary from `id` to copied object (so your original `lst` dictionaries are unchanged), then loop over *that structure* and and add entries to their manager id entry. I'm using the 'root nodes self-reference' rule (so the manager ID equals their own ID):

```
employees = {}
managers = set()
root_id = None
for emp in lst:
    id, mid = emp['id'], emp['ManagerID']
    # create a copy of emp, and add a "children" list
    employees[id] = {**emp, 'children': []}
    managers.add(mid)
    if id == mid:
        # the root of the tree references itself as the manager
        root_id = id

# add empty manager entries for missing manager IDs, reporting to root ID.
for id in managers - employees.keys():
    employees[id] = {
        'id': id, 'ManagerID': root_id, 'children': [],
        'job': None, 'name': None
    }

for id, emp in employees.items():
    manager = employees[emp.pop('ManagerID')]
    if id != root_id:  # don't add the root to anything
        manager['children'].append(emp)

output = employees[root_id]
```

The above uses a set to track what manager IDs have been seen, so you can trivially add missing manager entries (reporting to the CEO in this case).

For your input, that produces:

```
{'id': 0, 'job': 'CEO', 'name': 'John Smith', 'children':
    [{'id': 1, 'job': 'Medical Manager', 'name': 'Medic 1', 'children':
        [{'id': 2, 'job': 'Medical Assist', 'name': 'Medic 2', 'children': []}],
     },
     {'id': 3, 'job': 'ICT Manager', 'name': 'ICT 1', 'children':
        [{'id': 4, 'job': 'ICT Assist', 'name': 'ICT 2', 'children':
            [{'id': 5, 'job': 'ICT Junior', 'name': 'ICT 3', 'children': []}]
         }]
     }]
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining the treenodes in my original code! My data-source was not as neat as the example I gave, however, I found the full nested structure in position [62] out of [2000].

Answer (score 7):

Here is a recursive version for building the hierarchy.

### Recursive version

```
from pprint import pprint


def to_lookup(employees):
    employee_lookup = dict()
    for employee in employees:
        if employee["id"] != employee["ManagerID"]:
            manager_id = employee["ManagerID"]
            children = employee_lookup.get(manager_id)
            if not children:
                children = employee_lookup[manager_id] = list()
            children.append(employee.copy())
        else:
            manager = employee.copy()
    return manager, employee_lookup


def build_hierarchy(manager, employee_lookup):
    employees = employee_lookup.get(manager["id"], list())
    for employee in employees:
        build_hierarchy(employee, employee_lookup)
    if employees:
        manager['children'] = employees
    return manager


employees = [
    {"id": 0, "job": "CEO", "ManagerID": 0, "name": "John Smith"},
    {"id": 1, "job": "Medical Manager", "ManagerID": 0, "name": "Medic 1"},
    {"id": 2, "job": "Medical Assist", "ManagerID": 1, "name": "Medic 2"},
    {"id": 3, "job": "ICT Manager", "ManagerID": 0, "name": "ICT 1"},
    {"id": 4, "job": "ICT Assist", "ManagerID": 3, "name": "ICT 2"},
    {"id": 5, "job": "ICT Junior", "ManagerID": 4, "name": "ICT 3"}
]

manager, employee_lookup = to_lookup(employees)
hierarchy = build_hierarchy(manager, employee_lookup)
pprint(hierarchy)
```

### Output

```
{'ManagerID': 0,
 'children': [{'ManagerID': 0,
               'children': [{'ManagerID': 1,
                             'id': 2,
                             'job': 'Medical Assist',
                             'name': 'Medic 2'}],
               'id': 1,
               'job': 'Medical Manager',
               'name': 'Medic 1'},
              {'ManagerID': 0,
               'children': [{'ManagerID': 3,
                             'children': [{'ManagerID': 4,
                                           'id': 5,
                                           'job': 'ICT Junior',
                                           'name': 'ICT 3'}],
                             'id': 4,
                             'job': 'ICT Assist',
                             'name': 'ICT 2'}],
               'id': 3,
               'job': 'ICT Manager',
               'name': 'ICT 1'}],
 'id': 0,
 'job': 'CEO',
 'name': 'John Smith'}
```

### Performance test

```
hierarchy_size = 2000000

employees = [
    {"id": 0, "ManagerID": 0},
]
for idx in range(1, hierarchy_size):
    manager_id = random.randint(0, idx - 1)
    employees.append({"id": idx, "ManagerID": manager_id})

start = datetime.datetime.now()

manager, employee_lookup = to_lookup(employees)
hierarchy = build_hierarchy(manager, employee_lookup)

print(datetime.datetime.now() - start)
```

Comment: Thank you Andre for having a go at this. I've accepted @Martjin's answer as the solution because he helped me to understand my result.